# Moving down the fixed row numbers

Tags: google-sheets

Can you move the row numbers on the left side of the screen down?

I have a list that I need numbered, but the very top of the list (meaning the first row) has the categories for said list. So that row uses up Row 1 which means my list has to start at number 2. That gets confusing, as I always need to subtract one number from my list number.

So is there a way to move down the fixed numbers going down the page on the left-hand side of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.   That list of numbers shows you what row you are in.    If you need to have a column of numbers of at the left, put your own one in, and give it a category like "Id" or "RowNumber"